# Segfault on returning pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm searching through a vector of Contact objects (though the type of object shouldn't affect anything) and returning a pointer to the object if its found, or null otherwise. Below is the code:

```
Contact* searchByLastName(string lname) {

for (auto iter = LIST.begin(); iter != LIST.end(); ++iter) {
    Contact c = *iter; //Dereference 
    if (lname.compare(c.getLastName()) == 0) {
        return &c;
    }
}
return NULL;
}
```

If the method returns NULL (i.e. the Contact wasn't found in LIST), the code works fine. If the contact is in the list, the program segfaults.

I've tried using nullptr instead of NULL and returning a void pointer instead of a null pointer (and doing a static_cast back to Contact* if the result is not NULL/nullptr).

I'm not sure why its segfaulting. I know that NULL is defined as 0 in C++, but using nullptr (which should just be a pointer of type void*, right?) did not stop the segfaulting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are returning a pointer to Contact, return whatever that is pointed to by the iterator

```
return &(*iter);
```

instead of

```
return &c;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you please explain why that code doesn't segfault, but my original did?

Comment: Like all the other people that have commented. Because you are returning a local copy of Contact. The statement `Contact c = *iter;` calls the copy constructor of Contact to build a new Contact object on the stack. Then you return the address of the local Contact which isn't valid after function returns because it got destructed. This answer returns whatever that is actually pointed to by the iterator (ie. the actual object inside the list). This object does not get destructed after function returns. So it's still valid.

Answer (score 2):

You return the address of a local variable (`c`).

Comment: Is that a bad practice? If so, what's the best practice for returning a pointer?

Comment: Local variables exist on the stack, which ceases to exist after returning from the function, so the returned pointer will be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the address of a local variable, which will get destroyed once the function searchByLastName exits. You should return a pointer to what the iterator points to.